# Is the right pseudoinverse unique?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, pseudoinverse

It is well known that every $A\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$ admits a unique pseudoinverse. I fell a little bit confused, because if I consider the matrix
$$A=\begin{bmatrix}
4 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 5 & 0
\end{bmatrix}$$
if I try to compute hands-only (I mean, without using the given formula) the right pseudoinverse is the matrix
$$C=\begin{bmatrix}
c_{11} & c_{12} \\
c_{21} & c_{22} \\
c_{31} & c_{32}
\end{bmatrix}$$
such that
$$
A C=\begin{bmatrix}
4 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 5 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
\cdot
\begin{bmatrix}
1/4 & 0\\
0 & 1/5\\
c_{31} & c_{32}
\end{bmatrix} =\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0\\
0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}.
$$
So, it seems that the elements $c_{31}, c_{32}$ may remain "free", so that, by varying them, infinitely many right pseudoinverse may exist.

Could anyone please help me to understand what I am doing wrong?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What is your definition of a matrix's "pseudoinverse"? In the context where people say that a $2 \times 3$ matrix has a unique pseudoinverse, it is **not** the case that every right-inverse is a "pseudoinverse".

Comment: You're not doing anything wrong! Unlike true, two-sided inverses, right-inverses are not unique. As you know, your choices of c_31 and c_32 get destroyed by A, so they don't matter.

Comment: So, in general, what is the difference between a right inverse ad a pseudoinverse?